# Check for LOTS of cases within a switch case

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I have a switch statement and for each of the cases have a load of cases for that case.

Here is what I have so far.

```
exports.message = function message(message) {
  switch (message.toLowerCase()) {
    case "un":
    case "one":
    case "uno":
    case "um":
    case "unus":
    case "ano":
    case "un":
    //100 + other cases...
      return "Returned msg here"
    break;

    default: return "Sorry, I didn't quite understand that."

  }
}
```

After looking for answers on the internet the above fall-through is all I could find, but that's not going to do for me.

As some of my cases have up to 200 different possible "cases" I'm looking for another way. As doing it this way is not only ugly, long (200 lines just for a case) but also hard to manipulate if ever I want to change anything.

I would preferably like something like this:

```
exports.message = function message(message) {
  switch (message.toLowerCase()) {
    case ["un", "one", "uno", "um", "unus", "ano", "un", /* 100+ other cases...*/]
      return "Returned msg here"
    break;

    default: return "Sorry, I didn't quite understand that."

  }
}
```

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: A switch block is not appropriate for a large set of possible values. Just use a container object (such as Array) and test if the value is present.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash table, like

```
{
    un: true,
    one: true,
    uno: true,
    // ...
}
```

access with

```
if (hash[message.toLowerCase()]) { // ...
```

or an array, like

```
[
    "un", "one", "uno", "um", "unus", "ano", "un"
]
```

access with

```
if (array.indexOf(message.toLowerCase()) !== -1) { // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest putting the words from each `case` into an Object of Arrays, and using `Array.indexOf(caseWord) > -1` to see if that word is present in the Aray, something like:

```
var equivalentWordsFor = {
      'one' : ["un", "one", "uno", "um", "unus", "ano", "un"]
}

if (equivalentWordsFor.one.indexOf(message) > -1) {
    return "Returned message here.";
}
```

`Array.prototype.indexOf()` returns the index of the supplied string within the array upon which it's called; as this can include 0 (the index of the first element of a JavaScript Array), any positive number including zero represents a found match, whereas `-1` indicates that the supplied string was not found.

It would also be possible to use `Array.prototype.some()`:

```
var equivalentWordsFor = {
      'one' : ["un", "one", "uno", "um", "unus", "ano", "un"]
}

if (equivalentWordsFor.one.some(

    // 'word' is a reference to the current Array-element of the
    // Array over which we're iterating.

    // if 'word' is precisely equal to 'msg' the result is
    // of course 'true' and 'false' if not; if any element
    // satisfies this assessment Array.prototype.some() returns
    // true to the calling context, otherwise - if no element
    // satisfies the assessment - the method returns false:
    word => word === msg
)) {
    return "Returned message here.";
}
```

`Array.prototype.some()` returns a Boolean `true` if the supplied argument returns `true` for any element in the Array, and `false` if finds no elements matching the supplied argument.

Obviously both of these approaches require another Array for the 'two' word-equivalents and so on, but it should be much more maintainable than the equivalent approach using a `switch () {...}`.

References:

- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).
- [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

Comment: My apologies, amplungjan, looking at the timestamp it seems we each wrote our answers within the same minute. Plus, with the best will in the world, it's the most obvious and backwards compatible solution. If you prefer I'm happy enough to remove that component of the answer, and focus instead on `Array.prototype.some()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the following way:

```
var msg = message.toLowerCase()
if (~["un", "one", "uno", "um", "unus", "ano", "un", ...].indexOf(msg)) {
    // do something
} else if (~["deux", "two", "dos", ...].indexOf(msg)) {
    // do something else
} ...
```

Note that if you have a performance bottleneck, you'll want to put the most frequent cases at the beginning.

You might also want to remove duplicates from your list first for better performance (the one you sent contained "un" twice).

`array.indexOf(item)` returns the index of `item` in `array`, and `-1` if it isn't found.

`~x` is equivalent to `-x-1`. It'll return `true` if and only if `x != -1`.